# Discovering inconsistent results for scaning folder from php script and bash console

Tags: php, bash

here is very narrow question (as an opposite to "too broad" questions)
The output of this script

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$filename = '/tmp/password';

$handle = fopen($filename, 'r');

if ($handle)
{
    $username = fgets($handle);
    $password = fgets($handle);

    echo 'user='.$username.'<br>';
    echo 'pass='.$password.'<br>';
}
else
{
    echo 'handle= is false<br>';
}

if (file_exists($filename))
{
    echo "filename $filename exists<br>";
}
else
{
    echo "filename $filename does not exists<br>";
}

$dir = '/tmp';
$files_of_tmp_dir = scandir($dir);

print_r($files_of_tmp_dir);

?>
```

cause the following to be displayed

```
Warning: fopen(/tmp/password): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/mydomain/read_credentials.php on line 8
handle= is false
filename /tmp/password does not exists
Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => httpd_lua_shm.23475 )
```

Question:
Why there is only one user file 'httpd_lua_shm.23475', howerver

This command:

```
[root@newhostname tmp]# ls -l /tmp | wc -l
```

Returns 23.

And:

```
ls -l /tmp
```

Does not output file name 'httpd_lua_shm.23475' among those 23 files.

Is there any hacker here, who can simply explain such 'too broad' behaviour? :)

Okay, there is only miserable people who didn't read the question, but who can only downvote.

UPD:

Read, the question carefully (!).
The single file which is listed as output is not in the /tmp folder , even under root. This 'httpd_lua_shm.23475' does not exist in the /tmp folder under root. You are talking about permissions.
No hackers in stackoverflow? Come on! :)

UPD 2:
The problem is stated only with /tmp folder. Other folders are ok from working aspect. Going to find out why it's so and posting and answer.

Comment: It's probably because your web user and root user have different permissions to access that folder since its outside your web root.

Comment: Too broad answer. "drwxrwxrwt   20 apache apache   800 Jan 26 01:28 tmp" . Is it quite enough permittable?

Comment: Perhaps the temporary shm file was gone by the time you checked as root. I really think this has to do with file permissions. Please tell us which user created the password file and its permissions.
If this really isn't the problem, another simple explanation could be that you accidentally checked on a different host?

Comment: Obviously, `php` sees a different `/tmp` than `ls`. What do `hostname; df` from `bash` and `echo "<pre>".\`hostname; df\`."</pre>";` from your PHP script show?

Answer (score 1):

The user that runs the php script has different rights in the `tmp` directory than root.

Comment: Bad answer, why it's bad? It does not contain proposed solutions. You should argue your position that php script run as apache user, after changing /tmp folder's owner to apache user and group does not changes the output of file list. Your answer is too broad. I can tell you with 100% confidence.

Comment: did you also check the files' owners inside the directory? Which user creates the file /tmp/password?

Comment: and you really shouldn't change /tmp's owner, but you probably know that.

Comment: The question is not about should I change /tmp's owner or not. Let's me choose: do I need to change its owner or not, okay?

Comment: I am very sorry, Sir. Please choose your directories' owners as you please. I am sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: still, which user creates the file /tmp/passwords then?

Comment: I didn't vote your question down btw + I am sure this is a rights problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11026034)

Comment: @DanCornilescu I'm pretty sure it *does* answer the question.

Comment: @BenjaminW: maybe I misinterpreted OP's comment to this answer? Hm, OK, I admit it is a bit debatable...